# Laravel route parameter in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, view

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('{organisation}', 'Organisation\HomeController@index');
```

Now I need {organisation} in the AppServiceProvider my code there is as follows:

```
view()->composer('organisation.layout', function($view) {
        $view->with('categories', CategoryHelper::getCategoriesByOrganisation($organisation));
});
```

$organisation has to become the route parameter. I need to have categories available in the view all the time.

I've tried with `Input::get('organisation');` but no luck.

Is this the best approach? If yes, how do I get the route parameter?

Comment: Your problem is in receiving inputs ? If so Try `echo Input::all()` to Check all the inputs

Comment: Tried that, but zero results, while in controller it has results. I just don't know how to get the route parameter in AppServiceProvider.

Comment: You want to receive the param from route itself ?

Comment: If so Route::get('organisation/{data}', 'Organisation\HomeController@index');

Comment: Thanks for helping. In the controller it's easy. In HomeController I have a index($organisation) function. Organisation is filled here, but I want that value in the AppServiceProvider so I can have all time access to categories. How can I get {organisation} in AppServiceProvider?

Comment: You can do it by `public function __construct()` or Having the value in `AppServiceProvider` or create `Middleware` Class itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\App::make('request')->route()->getParameter('organisation')
```

**Is this the best approach.**
It depends on what you are doing.

If you simply loading the categories by organisation when someone is viewing an organization this should do fine.